Segmenting Time series with python
I have some task, where I just don't know how to solve it. I have a Time Series for productionsteps. Now I want to segment every productionstep and give it an ID. My Timeseries looks like this:

The numbers should be the ID. It should create an ID Column in my Time Series Dataframe.
I hope some one could help me.
I did try something like this:
# Identify new production cycles
production_day_copy['new_production_cycle'] = (production_day_copy['step'].shift() >= 88) & (production_day_copy['step'] < 18)
production_day_copy['production_cycle_id'] = (production_day_copy['new_production_cycle'].cumsum() + 1)

It did something that was ok, but it was confuse with those inbetween steps that suddenly drop from very high to 0.

can you give us a sample of your data?

This is a big Dataset. The Index is a Timestamp in '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S' and the Column "step" are the production steps that are shown on the y axis. The step is an integer. The time series could look like this [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,01,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,......,88,88,88,88,88,88,88,88,89,89,89,89,89,89,89,89, next cycle starts with step 18 or 0]

You can look for algorithms that can detect change points in time series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_detection. Pelt is well known https://centre-borelli.github.io/ruptures-docs/user-guide/detection/pelt/ but there are other ones too. Also check this question: Time series change point detection
